# Как собрать проект, использующий LLVM на Ubuntu?

Tags: llvm, ubuntu

Я скачал, собрал и установил из исходников LLVM. Пытаясь скомпилировать простой файл, использующий LLVM, я получаю ошибки.

Файл `sample.c`.

```
#include "llvm/System/DataTypes.h"

int main ()
{
  return 0;
}
```

Ошибки по команде `clang sample.c`.

```
/usr/local/include/llvm/System/DataTypes.h:45:3: error: 
    #error "Must #define __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS before #including System/DataTypes.h"
# error "Must #define __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS before #including System/DataTypes.h"
  ^
/usr/local/include/llvm/System/DataTypes.h:49:3: error: 
    #error "Must #define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS before #including System/DataTypes.h"
# error "Must #define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS before " \
  ^
2 errors generated.
```

Что нужно настроить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В папке `.../llvm/projects/` находится готовый проект, с которого стоит начать разработку собственного.

Шаги по использованию прописаны там: http://llvm.org/docs/Projects.html.